# Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5100, 5): [MSB3021] Unable to copy file "xxxx" to "xxx". Access to the path 'xxx' is denied jetbrain rider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rider, asp.net-core-6.0, jetbrains-rider

Upgraded the project from .net core 5 to 6 and getting this error on jetbrain rider, with visual studio everything is working fine.

```
  Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5100, 5): [MSB3021] Unable to copy file "C:\Projects\6clicks\src\LegalRegTech.Web.Host\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net6.0\LegalRegTech.Web.Host.exe". Access to the path 'C:\Projects\6clicks\src\LegalRegTech.Web.Host\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe' is denied.
```

[image]

I have given the full permission as well

[image]

Comment: Did you check with `procmon`/`procexp` who is holding the lock on the file?